# How can I make a directive that encloses the divs used in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My application uses this ***HTML*** to do an `ng-repeat`:

```
    <div class="gridBody">
        <div ng-class="{clicked: row.current == true}"
             ng-click="home.rowClicked($index)"
             ng-dblclick="ctrl.rowDoubleClicked(row)"
             ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view = (home.grid.data | orderBy:ctrl.examOrderBy[ctrl.configService.admin.examOrderBy].key:ctrl.configService.admin.examSortDirection) track by row.examId">
```

I understand how to do template directives but I am not sure if I can do a directive that calls another like here where it calls `ng-repeat`. How can I can create a directive that will allow me to call this code block like this:

```
    <div grid-body
         order="ctrl.examOrderBy[ctrl.configService.admin.examOrderBy].key"
         direction="ctrl.configService.admin.examSortDirection)"
         track="examId">
```

Basically I want a directive that combines the two `<div>`'s above into one. I think I need one that uses ***transclude*** but I am not sure how to use ***transclude*** and I could not find any examples that were like this.

Comment: Have you tried? Of course you can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you really want to do is Isolate Scope**

### Check my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8t0p4vLVcrio98Spy5W?p=preview)

Similar to your code, I use ng-repeat:

```
<div employeeform ng-repeat="emp in emplList" passed-model="emp">
</div>
```

The `employeeform` is my attribute directive. It is defined with it's own isolated scope and controller:

```
empApp.directive('employeeform', [
  function($compile) {

    function RowController($scope) {
      $scope.smyClass = "none";
      $scope.clickMe = function() {
        if ($scope.smyClass == "none") {
          $scope.smyClass = "clicked";
        } else {
          $scope.smyClass = "none";
        }
      };    
    }

    return {
      restrict: "A",
      controller: RowController,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        passedModel: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "Employee.html"
    };
  }
]);
```

The template `Employee.html` has references to the controller's local scope functions and smyClass property:

```
<div class="{{smyClass}}" ng-click="clickMe()" >
  <div style="display:inline-block; width: 100px;">{{ passedModel.name }}</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width: 100px;">{{ passedModel.position }}</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width: 100px;">{{ passedModel.salary }}</div>
</div>
```

Since I didn't have your data and other source, I created a simple tabular report. When you click on any row, the background turns yellow. When you unclick each row, it returns to it's normal white. This is my way of simulating click and unclick.

**Summary:**

When a directive has a defined local scope:

```
  scope: {
    passedModel: '='
  },
```

it shares nothing with the parent scope except for the parameters passed (e.g. passedModel). This leaves you free to use local variables to define the class of that particular row (directive).